# Flutter read from polar heart rate monitor

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to build an app with Flutter that can read data from a Polar H9 or H10 heart rate monitor (Bluetooth).

I must say that I am a bit lost and don't see how to do.

I would appreciate some clues and a little guidance for it.

Thank you very much !

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

The best way to start with any new BLE would be to look for any kind of documentation describing the process of connecting and accessing the data. I found the [official polar SDK](https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk) on GitHub. It's written for either iOS (Swift) or Android (Java) but might help you anyway.

In case it is not possible to use native libraries with flutter you should start by using a generic BLE scanner such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to find out more about the device and the available BLE services. It could be that nRF Connect already recognizes the Heart Rate Service in case Polar uses the official Service structure. If that's the case you need to read the specification of the Heart Rate Service (Found [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/)).

If they decided to use a custom service or protocol you could use nRF Connect to try to find out something about the device by sending some messages. This is a tedious process of try and error. A BLE sniffer might also help to collect data about existing communications between the sensor and a device.

Comment: Does this polar h10 send continuous Real time Live heart rate to our app? or it sends the Stored records? Can you help?

Comment: @Bernard Does this polar h10 send continuous Real time Live heart rate to our app? or it sends the Stored records? Can you help?